# Adding dynamic custom tab for WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking for a solution to add a custom tab for my product page in WooCommerce. I found already some solution like this code snippet below. But all that is for static contents. Is it possible to create a custom tab for product pages and where I can set the content individually in the admin product page? I know that there are plugins for that, but I'm trying to find a solution with using a plugin.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // 1) Removing tabs

    unset( $tabs['description'] );              // Remove the description tab
    // unset( $tabs['reviews'] );               // Remove the reviews tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove the additional information tab


    // 2 Adding new tabs and set the right order

    //Attribute Description tab
    $tabs['attrib_desc_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Desc', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 100,
        'callback'  => 'woo_attrib_desc_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the qty pricing  tab
    $tabs['qty_pricing_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Quantity Pricing', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 110,
        'callback'  => 'woo_qty_pricing_tab_content'
    );

    // Adds the other products tab
    $tabs['other_products_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Other Products', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 120,
        'callback'  => 'woo_other_products_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}

// New Tab contents

function woo_attrib_desc_tab_content() {
    // The attribute description tab content
    echo '<h2>Description</h2>';
    echo '<p>Custom description tab.</p>';
}
function woo_qty_pricing_tab_content() {
    // The qty pricing tab content
    echo '<h2>Quantity Pricing</h2>';
    echo '<p>Here\'s your quantity pricing tab.</p>';
}
function woo_other_products_tab_content() {
    // The other products tab content
    echo '<h2>Other Products</h2>';
    echo '<p>Here\'s your other products tab.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched and searched until I arrived at some example that includes variables in that 'callback' function - here is the cleanest example

```
/********************************************************
**  Remove, Create new product tabs and Prioritize
********************************************************/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'sgx_recreate_product_tabs', 98 );
function sgx_recreate_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    $productabs = get_field('prodtabs', $product->get_id());

    unset( $tabs['description'] );          // Remove description tab
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );   // Remove additional tab
    $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 50;          // push reviews priority back


    // loop through tabs created using ACF in this product backend.
    // i created a repeater with 2 fields - tabtitle & tabtxt
    if( !empty($productabs['tabs']) ) {
        $tabCounter = 1;

        foreach($productabs['tabs'] as $ptab) {
            $tabs['tab'.$tabCounter] = array(
                'title'     => $ptab['tabtitle'],
                'text'      => $ptab['tabtxt'],
                'priority'  => $tabCounter,
                'callback'  => 'sgx_custom_productab'
            );

            $tabCounter++;
        }
    }

    return $tabs;
}


    function sgx_custom_productab($slug, $tab) {
        echo ( !empty($tab['text']) ? $tab['text'] : '' );
    }
```

**Explanation:**
first, I created some tabs in the wp backend using ACF... now I want to dynamically add those but that callback function isn't dynamic....

However, that are some (apparently) variables I can use so I just added to the $tab array (in the first function) the data I needed and done.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a custom tab is possible through `woocommerce_product_tabs` filter.
For creating custom data field for your products I recommend to use [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

#### 1. Add a new field

- You need to [add a new field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/) for the products and add a name parameter for example `custom_detail`. (We use this in the code inside the `get_field` function). You can change its type for example *textarea* or *WYSIWYG*. In the roles section set **Post type | is equal to | product**.
- Now on the Edit product screen you can find your new field.

#### 2. Display the custom tab

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_product_tabs' );
function woo_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
  $tabs = array(
    'title' => 'Custom tab',
    'priority' => 20,
    'callback' => 'get_custom_product_tab_content',
  );
  return $tabs;
}

function get_custom_product_tab_content () {
  the_field('custom_detail');
}
```